# How to save a UserID without the Login in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, userid, revenuecat

I am pretty new to Kotlin. I was trying to implement the purchases through **RevenueCat** in my app but I need to have a **User ID** in order to identify the user and associate their purchases.

Typically you would have a Login, and use for example the Firebase ID, so that the User ID always stays the same for that specific user.

But I don't have a Login (since it wouldn't really make sense for my app), so I need to generate a User ID and save it somehow, so that it won't change even if the user deletes the app and reinstalls it, or if they change the device.

In my iOS app I simply used the **Key-Storage** from **iCloud** so that the User ID is saved and will always stay the same, even if the app is deleted or the user has a new device because the User ID is associated with their Apple ID basically.

I can't find a way to properly do it also in **Android** without a Login.

Does anyone have a suggestion about that? Is it even possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In android you can use Google account with firebase to achieve the same. Even though user change their device, you can identify with their Google account. You can even use Firebase for iOS too, which was useful to users, as they can have their same account in both iOS and Android.

In android by the combination of Google's Firebase auth and Sharedpreferences can save the user's preference, which was similar to iOS's userdefault.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I thought of using the Firebase ID, but I either get it from the Login/Sign-In (which I don't want to implement in such a simple app), or there is also the anonymous one but it won't be consistent throughout the devices and installations. Also SharedPreferences and UserDefaults get deleted if the app is deleted so I don't think they are an option.